# How to include the file during an Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using core php for a application, In that i have some views, classes, and javascript files.

view structure:

```
include('header.php'); //header file is included with config file
include('class.php');
<body>
include('fotter.php'); //footer file
```

When call for view is through redirect its all well.

Problem:
When I want to call some function of included class through ajax, i need to include the config file above the class by checking the ajax call.

How to use the preincluded file itself during ajax call as well.
Please help....

Comment: Put in short - you cannot include `*.php` file with `JavaScript`.

Comment: You dint get my problem - Is there any way to make the classes to use the config files all the time nobother that the call is by ajax or by redirect.